# JBossAS 7.1 + Apache2 Multiple Applications / web sites

Tags: deployment, jboss, apache2, jboss7.x

I need to deploy *www.first.com* and *www.second.com* on my Apache2 + JBoss7AS standalone environment.

I succesfully configured mod_jk and I have the first web app running.

Standalone.xml has:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="www.first.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

And my jboss-web.xml, in both application is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/test</security-domain>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

How can I have www.first.com point to first.war deployed app and www.second.com point to second.war deployed app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [JBoss AS7 Community Wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VirtualHostsWithJBossAS7?_sscc=t):

> To define other virtual hosts with your web app, don't forget to set
>   default-web-module to a name of the web module, which is the name of
>   the war without ".war" extension by default:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="virtualServerName">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http" scheme="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="first.com" default-web-module="first" enable-welcome-root="false">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="www.first.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
    <virtual-server name="second.com" default-web-module="second" enable-welcome-root="false">
        <alias name="www.second.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```